# Java proc.waitfor() is being ignored on mac

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, process

i ve written a simple program to run on a mac, the program opens an excel file and waits for the the user to close the file after which a simple output is given. when i run the program, excel opens, the proc.waitfor is ignored and it just skips to the output without waiting, any help
thanks

```
  Thread myThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String userDir = (System.getProperty("user.home"));

                String fileName = userDir + "/Desktop/test/testfile.xlsx";
                File theFile = new File(fileName);
                Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/open", fileName).start();
                int waitFor = proc.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MacTester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MacTester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };

    myThread.start();
    System.out.println("excel is now closed");
```

Comment: +1 for actually making this example. But I think it does not really relate to applets (Java applets usually even don't have the rights to create processes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:
`System.out.println("excel is now closed");`

Should be inside the run method. Your main thread, the thread that is starting your other thread continues with the execution after start has been invoked.

Another alternative is to place:
`myThread.join();`

on the line after:
`myThread.start();`

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/bin/open` doesn't run modally, it returns the control after launching the appropriate application. You should use `open -W`. Consider using `open -W -n` which opens the file in a new instance of the application. Consult `man open` and try in terminal before testing your java code.

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a distinction between closing a **document** on MacOS and closing an **application**. `/usr/bin/open` can detect the latter, but not the former.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your process (appropriately) in a background thread, and so what effect will waitfor have on the completely separate calling thread?  Answer: none. The solution I see has been given in the other answer -- +1 to him. :)